# Publish ASP.NET project with local data on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

I'm quite new to ASP.NET and I encountered a problem when publishing my project to Azure. After configuring the `connectionStrings` in `Web.config`, I have successfully uploaded my local database structure to Azure. However, all tables on Azure are now empty, without any local data. So how can I upload both the database structure as well as the data in it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use Entity Framework? Could you please provide more detailed code about  init database with local data for further research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To migrate an existing SQL Server database to Azure SQL Database you can export the schema as a TSQL script and then execute that script against Microsoft Azure SQL Database as follows:

1.Open `SQL Server Management Studio` and connect to an instance of the Database Engine.
In Object Explorer, right click a database to open a menu, select Tasks…, and then select Generate Scripts.

2.Choose objects to export.

3.Set scripting options. You have the options to save the script to file, clipboard, new query window; or publish it to a web service.

4.Set advanced scripting options.

You can also set the Types of data to script to one of the following based on your requirements: **Schema only**, **Data only**, **Schema and data**.

5.After the script is created, you have the option to modify the script before running the script against an Azure SQL Database to transfer the database.
You can now run this script on your Azure SQL Database.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](http://itproguru.com/expert/2015/03/how-to-move-or-migrate-sql-server-workload-to-azure-sql-database-cloud-services-or-azure-vm-all-version-of-sql-server-step-by-step/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a **post deployment script**. If the tables are created just fine on your azure application, then you must define what default data they will have. So in your post deployment script you will insert the data you want.